# uWSGI/nginx/Django poor performances after switching from Apache on Amazon EC2 Micro instances

Tags: django, apache, nginx, amazon-ec2, uwsgi

I have just switched my servers away from Apache/mod_wsgi to go towards a nginx/uwsgi stack. However, I am seeing very bad performances compared to Apache, even though the **server load is the same/even less during Christmas.** Any ideas as to why, I am very new to uWSGI/Nginx stack? Here is my configuration:

[uwsgi]

> chdir           = /srv/www/poka/app/poka 
>   module          = nginx.wsgi
>
> home            = /srv/www/poka/app/env/main
>
> env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.prod
>
> //master          = true
>
> processes = 10
>
> socket          = /srv/www/poka/app/poka/nginx/poka.sock
>
> chmod-socket    = 666
>
> vacuum          = true
>
> pidfile = /tmp/project-master.pid
>
> harakiri = 60
>
> max-requests = 5000

daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/poka.log

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to identify where the problem is. Assuming you don't do anything fanzy, like requests with huge payloads, I do a few things:

**nginx:** Log duration of upstream requests with [$upstream_response_time](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html). Compare it to total response time with [$request_time](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html). This tells you, where the time is lost, i.e. if nginx has a problem, or the upstream components (uwsgi, django, database, …) If uwsgi is the problem …

**uwsgi:** enable the [stats server](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/StatsServer.html), then use [uwsgitop](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgitop) to get a quick overview of the stats
If uwsgi is fine, look into what Python/Django is doing …

**uwsgi+python:** enable [pytracebacker-sockets](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Tracebacker.html) to view what the workers are *doing*. If you see workers getting stuck, enable (if that is reasonable in your scenario) harakiri-mode, so uwsgi can recycle stuck workers. When using harakiri do not forget to enable the pytracebacker, as that will give you *Python* stacktraces when a worker is killed.

**Django:** Enable the [debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) to see where and how much the application is spending its time.

When you've identified the component, you're already much closer to a solution, and can ask much more specific questions.

(If you *are* doing big requests, then compression settings and max-payload-related settings of uwsgi/nginx may be good candidates to look into. They caused us some headaches.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need 10 processes? Why you don't try a minor amount? uWSGI + Nginx can handle lot of concurrent requests just with 2/4 processes, perhaps the bottleneck is there.

Comment: I changed it to 2. We'll see how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

you can

1. monitor cpu/mem for detail comparison
2. install uwsgitop(via pip install uwsgitop) to monitor your uwsgi process